# Why we use ++ in toc[0].out++ in Tictoc10?

Tags: networking, omnet++

In OMNeT++ Tictoc tutorial, Step3:Turning into a real network:in network Tictoc10:in connections why we use '++' in  toc[0].out++ ?It is not there in Tictoc9

Comment: Same question has been nicely answered on [the OMNeT++ mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/c7qSPxrAsSc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained in the section 3.9 of [omnet++ simulation manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/):

> The gatename++ notation causes the first unconnected gate index to be
>   used.